# Finite-time Fourier transform of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform

Can someone explain this formula to me? 
Given a wave packet whose time evolution is $g(t)$, a partially resolved spectrum is found by Fourier transforming its overlap with the same wave packet at time $t=0$, $g$. 
$$E_T(\omega) = (1/2\pi)\int_{-T}^T \exp(i\omega t)<g|g(t)> dt \\
= (1/\pi)\sum_n \frac {\sin(E_n/\hbar - \omega)T}{(E_n/\hbar - \omega)}~|\langle g|\psi_n\rangle |^2.$$

I don't understand how the second formula is found.

Answer (score 2):

This is but a sum of [cardinal sine functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) with peaks at $\omega = E_n/\hbar$, for all *n*. Absorb $\hbar$ into the *E*s out of respect for sanity.

Recall
$$
|g\rangle=\sum_n |\psi_n\rangle \langle \psi_n|g\rangle, \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 
|g(t)\rangle=\sum_n |\psi_n\rangle e^{-iE_nt}\langle \psi_n|g\rangle ,
$$
so that 
$$
(1/2\pi)\int_{-T}^T \!\!dt ~ e^{i\omega t}\langle g|g(t)\rangle = 
(1/2\pi)\int_{-T}^T \!\!dt ~ e^{i\omega t}\sum_n e^{-iE_n t}|\langle g|\psi_n\rangle |^2 \\ 
= (1/\pi)\sum_n\frac{\sin (E_n - \omega)T}{E_n - \omega} ~|\langle g|\psi_n\rangle |^2 ,$$
upon integration.

Comment: Thank you very much! So clear!

Comment: So you clicked on the check mark?